# Moving WordPress blog to new domain

Tags: seo, blog, migration

I created a website and a blog. Assume the website address is `example.com`. And I added a blog (WordPress) to that website at `example.com/blog`.

I need to move my blog to a new domain (only the blog). I don't want to lose SEO traffic also which I have for my blog.

What is the best way to move my blog to new domain?

Answer (score 1):

You could write a command in *.htaccess* file like this:

```
Redirect 302 /folder/oldpage.html http://www.example.org/newpage.html
```

By this whenever someone accesses `http://www.example.com/folder/oldpage.html`, their web browser will take them to `http://www.example.org/newpage.html` instead.

For 301:

```
Redirect 301 /folder/oldpage.html http://www.example.org/newpage.html
```

Comment: Use 301 -moved permanently